# Betaflight and Mamba F405 mk2: no gyro after flashing the FC

Tags: flight-controller, betaflight, imu

I flashed my Mamba F405 into latest firmware by Betaflight Configurator and gyro is not working after this. Everything was OK on the dafault firmware but now it don't work on any.

How to fix it? Did flashing damage the IMU chip?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of this problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksxONEal7yo

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) can become invalid if the linked page is removed or changes.